# golang get values from interface{}

Tags: go, go-interface

I am iterating through the results returned from a couchDB.View and extracting the Key.

```
for _, row := range rows {
        fmt.Printf("%v, %T\n", row.Key, row.Key)
    }
```

The result of this is:

```
[nh001 mgr], []interface {}
[nh002 nh], []interface {}
```

I need to read through this interface and get the 2nd value ("mgr" or "nh").

I am not able to iterate over this as this is not a map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your value `row.Key` is returned from somewhere as `interface{}`?

If yes then in your `range rows` you can try to cast it to type `[]interface{}`. So your code should look something like this.

```
for _, row := range rows {
    if val, ok := row.Key.([]interface{}); ok {
        fmt.Println(val[1])
    }
}
```